# Пересылка сообщений для VK бота

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api

Такой вопрос: Как правильно сделать, чтобы бот ВК в беседе пересылал сообщение, на которое он реагирует? Пример на скрине:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вроде как в интернетах принято называть этот процесс цитированием, а не пересылкой.

Answer (score 4):

> https://vk.com/dev/messages.send

Не знаю с какой именно библиотекой для VK API вы работаете, но рекомендую часто обращаться к оригинальной документации.
В данном случае нужно вытянуть **id сообщения** и присвоить его значение к **forward_messages** или же **reply_to** (как вам удобнее)

Comment: Благодарю за помощь.